# Bring Unique data from two database db1 and db2 on same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two database name db1 and db2 on same server, I need a sql query to get unique data. Below are databases and tables name

**db1**

**Table_db1**

```
EmailID           Name     Mobile
raj@gmail.com     raj      7207542655
kumar@gmail.com   kumar    111111111
```

**db2**

**Table_db2**

```
 EmailID          Name     Mobile
raj@gmail.com     raj      7207542655
rohan@gmail.com   rohan    5555555555
```

raj@gmail.com removed duplicate from tables and Output should be

```
raj@gmail.com     raj      7207542655
kumar@gmail.com   kumar    111111111
rohan@gmail.com   rohan    5555555555
```

I need unique data from db1 and db2 base on EmailID of Table_db1 and Table_db2

bring single EmailID data from Table_db1 and Table_db2

Comment: any one in stack over flow.@all

Comment: Some data and expected output may help to understand the question completely.

Comment: output will same columns EmailID Name Mobile. @Susang

Comment: I updated my question. @Susang

Comment: hi mazhar, name and mobile number also same in both table?

Comment: No, column name and mobile are different. @PradipMeghapra

Comment: In this case we can bring T1.Name,T1,Mobile like that na. @PradipMeghapra

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
 SELECT distinct te1.Emailid, (select top 1 [name] from [db1].dbo._Table_1 as te11 where te11.emailid = te1.emailid) as [Name]
  FROM [db1].dbo._Table_1 as te1
 WHERE EXISTS  (
               SELECT emailId 
                 FROM [db2].dbo._Table_1 as te2
                WHERE te1.emailid = te2.emailid
              )  

UNION

SELECT distinct te1.Emailid, (select top 1 [name] from [db1].dbo._Table_1 as te11 where te11.emailid = te1.emailid) as [Name]
  FROM [db1].dbo._Table_1 as te1
 WHERE not EXISTS  (
               SELECT emailId 
                 FROM [db2].dbo._Table_1 as te2
                WHERE te1.emailid = te2.emailid
              )  


UNION

SELECT distinct te2.Emailid, (select top 1 [name] from [db2].dbo._Table_1 as te22 where te22.emailid = te2.emailid) as [Name]
  FROM [db2].dbo._Table_1 as te2
 WHERE not EXISTS  (
               SELECT emailId 
                 FROM  [db1].dbo._Table_1 as te1
                WHERE te1.emailid = te2.emailid
              )
```

Comment: I am trying this: select a.*,b.* from
IntranetNew_Live.dbo.Table_CandidateMaster as a --DB1= first database name, dbo=schema(fix no change), tbl1=table from first database, a= alias of whole path (DB1.dbo.tbl1)
left join
Intranet_NewVersion.dbo.Table_CandidateMaster as b  --DB2= second database name, dbo=schema(fix no change), tbl2=table from second database, b= alias of whole path (DB2.dbo.tbl2)
on a.EMail=b.EMail .@Pradip Meghapra

Comment: I will check your query will inform you. @Pradip Meghapra

Answer (score 0):

Your rows are exactly the same.  Just use `union`:

```
select EmailID, Name, Mobile
from Table_db1
union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select EmailID, Name, Mobile
from Table_db2;
```

If the other columns can be different and there are no duplicates within a table, then:

```
select EmailID, Name, Mobile
from Table_db1
union all
select EmailID, Name, Mobile
from Table_db2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from Table_db1 t1 where t1.EmailID = t2.EmailID);
```